# Use custom folder(class) in controller

Tags: laravel

I created a new folder in the directory `app` which is called `Services`. So the directory of Services is `app/Services`. I want to use now a file of Services called `Connection.php` in a Controller app/Http/Controllers but when I try that, I get following error:

> Class App\Services\Connection does not exist

I also tried to add the directory and file in my composer.json but this didn't fixed it either.

Controller:

```
namespace App\Services;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Services\Connection;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    protected $conn;
    public function __construct(Connection $conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
```

Composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Services"
        ],

"autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/Services/Connection.php"
        ]
    },
```

**Edit 17.12.2016:** (problem not solved yet)

Thanks for all who stick with me so long on this problem! I'm sry, if I gave too less information so I'll sum up few things that I tried.

1 => Deleted the secound namespace `App\Services`

2 => Added routes(or directory) to my composer.json ( like above )

3 => Used `composer updated` and composer `dump-autoload`

4 => Used `use App\Services\Connection` (the path to my connection class in Services, which I want to use in my ExampleController in `App\Http\Controllers\ExampleController`)

Connection class:

```
class Connection
{
    //Some guzzle stuff
}
```

So the ExampleController looks exact as above just without the Services namespace anymore and I get exact the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your Connection class. Can you upload it?

Comment: I could give an example of it how it looks like but the actual process of the class shouldn't be that important, because he just doesn't find the class. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I really just need the namespace part of the Connection class in App\Services. Just to make sure your namespace isn't messed up on the class.

Comment: I did not understand this @ScottPlunkett but now I do. I really had to add the namespace `App\Services` in my `connection` class within `App\Services`. Wow. Thank you for helping me! :)

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you got it resolved. Can't really mark this as an answer but I appreciate you letting me know it was resolved.

Comment: You could make an answer and sum up these things if you want. I would accept it!

Comment: Sure thing! It was just submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presented this solution as a comment but to make it easier for future viewers:

The solution to this is to ensure that proper name spacing is in all files being referenced including the controller and the classes. If the namespace isn't correct it won't be able to access it.

In this case you have to make sure that the namespace for the Connection class was using `App\Services` as the namespace and that the controller accessed it in the same namespace of `App\Services\Connection`.

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\Connection;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct(Guard $auth, Connection $conn)
  {
     $this->auth = $auth;
     $this->conn = $conn;
  }
}
```

Please try to use this code.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'll but for what do I need this `Guard $auth`?

Comment: basically use for authentication purpose. you can create custom guard also. please refer laravel.com for details about authentication

Comment: I don't have an issue with authentication. I've got an issue with `Class App\Services\Connection does not exist` as you can take from my question

Comment: then please use this name space and composer dump auto load ..it ll be work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on your namespace declaration. you are declaring two namespaces for the same class!

```
namespace App\Services;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

The last one will be used.

Remove the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace line.

Also remember that you should import the base controller:

```
use App\Controllers\Controller;
```

## Why?

When you try to use `App\Services\ExampleController`, composer will look for that class in the autoload paths, but since your namespace is different, it will not be able to load it.

Comment: Since this is a Controller, the line `namespace App\Services;` should be removed.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I removed the namespace `App\Services` but the error is the same. When I try to add use `App\Controllers\Controller` it doesn't find him too.

Comment: thissven because its not `App\Controllers` its `App\Http\Controllers`

Comment: Oh, yes, sry, my fault but still got the issue `Class App\Services\Connection does not exist`